# Is there an identity related to $\binom{n-j-1}{k}+\binom{k+j}{k}\pmod{n}$?

Tags: prime-numbers, binomial-coefficients, congruences

I noticed that when $n$ is an odd prime, the following congruence
$$\binom{n-j-1}{k}+\binom{k+j}{k} \equiv 0 \pmod{n}$$ 
holds for $0 \le j \le \frac{(n-k)}2$ and odd values of $k$ such that $0 < k < n$.

Is there an identity that relates the above sum of binomials $\pmod{n}$ for any values of $n$ (no matter if it's prime or composite) and $k$ (odd and even values)?

Comment: Take $k=n-1,j=0$ Then the binomials sum to 2 for all $n$ (note that unlike your case $n,k$ have opposite parity). If $k=n-2,j=0$ then the binomials sum to $n$ for all $n$. So I don't think you will have any simple relation.